# Setting iptables for captive portal ap

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, http, python, iptables

I have problem on my nethunter device with iptables (version 1.6).
I have created flask server (http port 80) and script that create ap using hostapd

For redirection I use dnsmasq (10.0.0.1 address)

dnsmasq conf:

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.100,8h
dhcp-option=3,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.1
address=/#/10.0.0.1
no-resolv
```

Command to setup interface & enable port forwarding:

```
os.system('route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.1')
os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward')
```

Iptables config below:

```
os.system('iptables -F') # Flush old iptables rules
os.system('iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT') # Enable traffic on localhost
os.system('iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT') # Allow http connection
```

It is working on my desktop, but i dont know why it's not working on nethunter. Iptables aren't showing any errors, AP and server is starting but pop-up login message wont show on other mobile device

Please explain if something is wrong with iptables config or anything that can cause that problem

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you tried using WireShark?

Comment: What you show here is not "port forwarding" so your problem not related to iptables issues